# Potential buggy content in caesar cipher website

Tags: caesar-cipher

I'm writing a program to perform simple caesar decryption and encryption. I looked at the tutorial via the link [http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/papers/MSTP/crypto/3Caesar_Cipher.html](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Escott/papers/MSTP/crypto/3Caesar_Cipher.html). My question is that to encrypt the string `abcde fghij klmno pqrst uvwxy z` to `XYZAB CDEFG HIJKL MNOPQ RSTUV W`. Do we need to shift the letters by 23 instead of 3 if we ignore the upper case? Also, the encryption of the string `veni vidi vici` seems to be incorrect. I got `SBKF SFAF SFZF` not `SBKF SFGF SFZF`

Comment: You shift in the wrong direction. The website shits the string to left by 3 letter2. You are thinking about shifting the string to right.